# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null using array

Tags: javascript

My JS is throwing this error even when i'm checking if it's null or not. Maybe one of you guys could help me with this one.

```
if (typeof(this.callbacks['changed']) !== 'undefined') {
        if (typeof(obj['item']['data']) !== 'undefined' && 
           (typeof(obj['item']['data'] != null))) {
            this.callbacks['changed'](row, obj['item']['data']);
        }
    }
```

This error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null

already starts here: `&& (typeof(obj['item']['data'] != null)`

Comment: What is the object? Console log it

Comment: `obj['item']` doesn't exist or it is `null`.

Comment: You can simplify all this to `if(this.callbacks && this.callbacks.changed && obj && obj.item && obj.item.data){...}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answers. Even when i change the check to: if (typeof(obj['data'] != null)) {
    this.callbacks['changed'](row, obj['item']['data']);
   } it will still return a error on after the !null check..

Comment: I'm glad I could help, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (typeof(this.callbacks['changed']) !== 'undefined') {
        if (obj && obj.item && typeof(obj['item']['data']) !== 'undefined' && (typeof(obj['item']['data'] != null))) {
            this.callbacks['changed'](row, obj['item']['data']);
        }
    }
```